# I've set up External Secrets on an AKS Cluster, pointed to an Azure Key Vault, but my ExternalSecrets won't sync

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, external-secrets-operator

I'm trying to integrate AKS with Key Vault using the [External Secrets](https://external-secrets.io) operator. I've set up the operator itself using the Helm chart, and I've created a `SecretStore` resource pointed at a Vault (we'll call it `keyvault-demo`). However when I attempt to create `ExternalSecret` resources, the status says `SecretSyncedError` and provides no meaningful error beyond "`could not get secret data from provider`".

Here's the YAML for both the `SecretStore` and the `ExternalSecret`:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: SecretStore
metadata:
  name: azure-backend
spec:
  provider:
    azurekv:
      tenantId: <REDACTED>
      vaultUrl: "https://<redacted>.vault.azure.net/"
      authType: ServicePrincipal
      authSecretRef:
        clientId:
          name: azure-secret-sp
          key: ClientID
        clientSecret:
          name: azure-secret-sp
          key: ClientSecret
```

```yaml
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: azure-example
spec:
  refreshInterval: 15m
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: azure-backend
  target:
    name: azure-secret
  data:
  - secretKey: foobar
    remoteRef:
      key: secret/example-externalsecret-key
```

I've verified that the names of the Key Vault, the Service Principal, and the secret within the Vault are all correct. What am I missing here??

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Understood, I've moved it over to the DevOps community: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/18847/ive-set-up-external-secrets-on-an-aks-cluster-pointed-to-an-azure-key-vault-b

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `ExternalSecret` is missing `spec.data[0].remoteRef.property`...
See [this](https://external-secrets.io/latest/api/externalsecret/) for more info.